# I'm following a tutorial on [Python + OpenCV + mediapipe] Hand Tracking and I get the following error:

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

I get the following error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

And this is my code

```
import mediapipe as mp
import time
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
 
mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands()
mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
 
pTime = 0
cTime = 0
 
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = hands.process(imgRGB)
    # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)
 
    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for handLms in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                print(id, cx, cy)
                # if id == 4:
                cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
 
            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
 
    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
    pTime = cTime
 
    cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                (255, 0, 255), 3)
 
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check and add these lines.

```
...
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) # Additional argument here
 
...
while cap.isOpened():
    success, img = cap.read()
    if not success: # Add break if not successful
         break
    ...
    cv2.waitKey(1)

# This will close the capture and cv2 properly
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```